# How to redirect requests from port A at IP A to port B at IP B

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, port

I have a number of laptops on my home network's router. Unfortunately the router has only one computer that can run on port 80 and be open to the external world.

Is it possible for me to use a cheap VPS as a proxy to another computer running a site on my home network? The VPS would receive requests on port 80 and have a domain name. But it would really just be a "front" for whatever site I have running on port XYZ on my home router.

I'm interested in doing this for both port 80 and the typical SSH ports and of course port 440, with each going to non-standard ports on my home router and then the subsequent computer mapped to it. Is this possible to do using nodejs or express, or some other library?

Comment: For starters, you should look up "port forwarding" on your own router.  Then, you probably need to move this out of stack overflow because this is more of a networking problem (typically solved by network equipment), probably not really a stack overflow topic.

Comment: I know how to map ports from the home router to the computer. It's from the VPS with its own port 80 to the home router's forwarding port that I need help with.